# What is the `it` in Kotlin lambda body?

Tags: java, file, jvm, kotlin

For example in these two following codes:

```
File("./file1.txt").forEachLine { println(it) }
```

and

```
File("somefile.txt").bufferedWriter().use { out ->
    history.forEach {
        out.write("${it.key}, ${it.value}\n")
    }
}
```

In this code what does `it` mean?

Comment: https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/lambdas.html#it-implicit-name-of-a-single-parameter

Comment: How can we rename it parameter?

Comment: Just put some variable name and use it. eg. randomList.map { myVariable -> print(myVariable) }

Answer (score 56, accepted):

[it](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/lambdas.html#it-implicit-name-of-a-single-parameter) variable is an implicit parameter in lambda.

> One other helpful convention is that if a function literal has only **one parameter**, its declaration may be omitted (along with the ->), and its name will be **it**:

Answer (score 10):

Here is the kotlin org doc: [it: implicit name of a single parameter](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/lambdas.html#it-implicit-name-of-a-single-parameter)

for example

```
ints.filter { value -> value > 0 }
```

you can simplify it to:

```
ints.filter { it > 0 }
```

while you cannot use

```
ints.filter { value > 0 }
```

Answer (score 8):

Please refer to the following description.

> **it: implicit name of a single parameter**
>
> It's very common that a lambda expression has only one parameter.
>
> If the compiler can figure the signature out itself, it is allowed not
>   to declare the only parameter and omit ->. The parameter will be
>   implicitly declared under the name it:

```
ints.filter { it > 0 } // this literal is of type '(it: Int) -> Boolean'
```

https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/lambdas.html#it-implicit-name-of-a-single-parameter

Answer (score 3):

```
val list = listOf(1,2,3,4,5,6,7).filter { it > 2 }
for(i in list){
    println(i)
}
```

In this Example, list size is 7. Using **it**, list size is 5. for loop only check > 2 numbers

> size = 5 and output is 3,4,5,6,7

Comment: It's not because of using 'it' that the size of the list is 5, but because a filter is applied. Incidentally, 'it' is used to simplify the expression.