# What are this, it, activity in kotlin android exactly?

Tags: android, kotlin

I am new to android and following the official Android guide.
Sometimes I can't understand some keywords in the example codes,
like `it`, `this`, and `activity`.

Suppose I have to call a dialog like this:

```
SampleDialog().show(this@MainActivity.supportFragmentManager, null)
```

What does `this@Activity` mean?

Comment: See [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41617042/how-to-access-activity-this-in-kotlin) for `this@MainActivity` and [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44773351/what-is-the-it-in-kotlin-lambda-body) for `it`. For general information on Kotlin, see https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/

Comment: I would suggest that you learn the technologies in this order: Java, Android, Kotlin

Answer (score 3):

`this` is like a `this` keyword from Java which is a reference to the current object. So, `this@MainActivity` in Kotlin is equivalent to `MainActivity.this` in Java. Can read more at [this](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/this-expressions.html#qualified) and [this](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/thiskey.html).

[it](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/lambdas.html#it-implicit-name-of-a-single-parameter) is an implicit name of a single parameter in lambda function.

`activity` is like `getActivity()` when calling from a fragment. It returns the FragmentActivity this calling fragment is currently associated with.